# Create setenv.sh to set system property

Tags: linux, tomcat, java, shell

I have to use setenv.sh to set system properties on Linux with Tomcat Server 6.

As described here [Linux Environment- setenv.sh](http://www.liferaysavvy.com/2012/09/setting-environment-variables-and.html), I have created a setenv.sh in tomcat/bin, and the only think I added is the

```
export JAVA_OPTS =”-Dmyprojectvar.subname=value -Danothervariable=value -Danother.variable=value”
```

I don't know, is this enough to set the properties. I just want to add three properties to tomcat as system property using setenv.sh. What should I do to complete it successfully? What are the steps for it?

I saw this question [setenv.sh is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18697584/setenv-sh-is-not-working).  No is answer given there and I don't  understand the question. Do we need to set `CATALINA_HOME` and other properties somewhere in `setenv.sh?`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the problem you have is magic quotes, note that `”` (U+201D : RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK) is not the same as `"` (U+0022 : QUOTATION MARK), the former will cause your shell script to fail (this is a prblem you need to watch out for when copying from people's blogs) e.g.

> setenv.sh: line 1: export: `-Danothervariable=value': not a valid identifier
>
> setenv.sh: line 1: export: `-Danother.variable=value”': not a valid identifier

Try this which used `"`

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-Dmyprojectvar.subname=value -Danothervariable=value -Danother.variable=value"
```

---

I just noticed you have a space between = and " that shouldn't be there either.

Comment: Still the problem exist  Shows "/catalina.sh: 1: export: : bad variable name"
when I am trying to run catalina.sh

Comment: See my update, also see your manager about some much needed education in shell basics - you really need it.